# Access JSP web service using third party tool

Tags: java, web-services, jsp

I have a webservice

https://stg-xyz.com/Quote/xmlgateway/GetRate.jsp
I can call this using webclient in .net and pass serialized xml and it works fine.
Is there a third party tool to pass data(VIN etc) to this JSP service and get the output back.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean an HttpClient?

Comment: No,  WebClient wc = new WebClient();

Comment: I meant: are you looking for an HTTP client to send HTTP requests? Apache has one, Spring has one, etc.

Comment: No, I was looking for some utility tool where I can copy/paste this URL and add payloads. Click on some button and see the output.

Comment: Use a browser. Unless you parse the html returned by the jsp you won't know which fields to enter. The whole point of a web service is to know what the interface is.

Answer (score 0):

Any HTTP POST tool will work for your use case. You can use [wfetch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284285).